# string comparison not working with httpresponse

Tags: java, android, string, httpresponse

I have a server response `response` which is converted to string by method `EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())`which gives a string **campus** but when compared to original string **S=campus** by `S.equals("campus")` its returns false .

```
response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
S= EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
Log.e("Test",S);
if(S.equals("campus"))
        Log.e("Test","this string is not printing");
```

Comment: you forget brackets.

Comment: mistake while typing

Comment: bug in Matrix? ... obviously `S` is not equals `"campus"` ...

Comment: what? i didnt get it .

Comment: http://ideone.com/MOiJx7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They Maybe look equal but they are not! Try "contains(String)" or "startswith(String)".